# MongoDb find() returns a lot of unwanted fields

Tags: node.js, mongodb, rest

```
 app.get('/',function(req,res){
        var response={};
        db.collection('first').find({},function(err,result){
            if(err){
                db.close();
                console.log('Error');
                console.log(err);
            }
            else{
                db.close();
                console.log('Success');
                console.log(response);
            }
        });

        res.end(response);
    });
```

However, this returns a lot of unwanted data. I looked through that data too, but I do not see the entry values/fields made in the collection. I want it to return field values only as a JSON object. How should I do this ?

Sample output: (Too much to post everything)

```
Readable {
  connection: null,
  server: null,
  disconnectHandler: 
   { s: { storedOps: [], storeOptions: [Object], topology: [Object] },
     length: [Getter] },
  bson: {},
  ns: '****',
  cmd: 
   { find: '******',
     limit: 0,
     skip: 0,
     query: {},
     slaveOk: true,
     readPreference: { preference: 'primary', tags: undefined, options: undefined } },
  options: 
   { skip: 0,
     limit: 0,
     raw: undefined,
     hint: null,
     timeout: undefined,
     slaveOk: true,
     readPreference: { preference: 'primary', tags: undefined, options: undefined },
     db: 
      EventEmitter {
        domain: null,
        _events: {},
        _eventsCount: 0,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        s: [Object],
        serverConfig: [Getter],
        bufferMaxEntries: [Getter],
        databaseName: [Getter],
        options: [Getter],
        native_parser: [Getter],
        slaveOk: [Getter],
        writeConcern: [Getter] },
     promiseLibrary: [Function: Promise],
     disconnectHandler: { s: [Object], length: [Getter] } },
  topology: 
   EventEmitter {
     domain: null,
     _events: 
      { reconnect: [Function],
        timeout: [Object],
        error: [Object],
        close: [Function],
        destroy: [Object] },
     _eventsCount: 5,
     _maxListeners: undefined,
```

and more......

Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, you're logging and sending back an empty `response` object. Your issue come from the syntax, [`find()`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/api/Collection.html#find) takes only one parameter and returns a cursor, you have to call `next()` on it inside a loop to get every document or call `toArray()` to get all documents at once:

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    db.collection('first').find({}).toArray(function (err, docs) {
        db.close();

        if (err) {
            console.log('Error');
            console.log(err);
            res.end();
        }
        else {
            console.log('Success');
            console.log(docs);
            res.json(docs);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you.